# MySQL JOIN, IF Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that look like this:

```
SalesPeople
-----------
SalesID, FirstName, LastName, Supervisor

Members
-------
MemberID, Firstname, LastName, Region, SalesID
```

In an attempt to show every salesperson's ID and the Members to they are assigned. I wrote the following SQL query:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM salespeople s
INNER JOIN members m ON s.salesid = m.salesid
```

However, If the salesperson is not assigned to any member I need to say, 'No Members Assigned' for that output. I also would like to label the MemberID column as, 'Clients'.

The above code works, but when I try to label the Members MemberID column as 'Clients' I get an error:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM salespeople s
INNER JOIN members m AS Clients ON s.salesid = m.salesid
```

Again the my question is:

How do I show salesperson's `SalesID` and the `MemberID` that match.  If a salesperson is not assigned to any members just show it anyway with: "No Members Assigned."  As I stated above I need to label the column showing the `MemberID` column as `Clients`.

If this is confusing in anyway I am more than happy to clarify.

Comment: Left join is different than inner join because it will only give us members (in this case) that match salespeople.

Comment: @cryptomath No, the `LEFT JOIN` will show you all salespeople, and those which have no match in `members` will have `NULL` values for the `members` columns. Then it's a matter of using something like `CASE WHEN Members.MemberID IS NULL THEN 'No Members Assigned' ELSE MemberID END AS Clients`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT s.*, COALESCE(m.memberId, 'No Members Assigned') clients
FROM salespeople s
LEFT JOIN members m ON s.salesid = m.salesid
```

The `LEFT JOIN` will get you `m.memberId` as null when there is no member for that sales person.

The `COALESCE` function will return the first non-null argument sent as input. So in this case, if the `m.memberId` is null then `'No Members Assigned'` will be returned.

The result of combining both of them is the one you expect.